# How to maintain the flow of my loop while having scanf input? (console refreshing)

Tags: c++, loops, scanf

I currently am creating a Word Search game that requires the entire console to be refreshed so my countdown clock is updated every second. I've done this using a loop with `sleep(1)` and `system("cls");` , followed by calling all my functions back to refresh. 
However I also need to have user input so that the user can enter a word that they've found in the word search

```
char guessWord[100] = " ";
printf("\nWord: ");
scanf("%s", &guessWord);
```

The problem is the the console is constantly waiting for input which disrupting the flow of the loop. Is it possible to have it to scan for one second then somehow break, so that it loops/ updates and then scans again?

Comment: You could put the user input in another thread, but even that will look dodgy. Look into a curses-like library for whatever platform you are using. Oh, and `scanf`? Is this the 1970's?

Comment: Is this C or C++ code?

Comment: this is C++ code